# Передать значения чекбоксов формы в php

Tags: php, html, form

К примеру в форме есть чекбоксы с несколькими вариантами:

```
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="ch[]" id="ch-1" value="val-1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="ch[]" id="ch-2" value="val-2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="ch[]" id="ch-3" value="val-3">

</form>
```

В js обычная обработка формы (не суть):

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'contacts.php',
  type: 'post',
  data: str
}).done(function(msg) { .... }
```

И есть **contacts.php**:

```
<?php

    define("CONTACT_FORM", 'test@mail.ru'); 

    $subject = 'Заявка';

    $ch  = stripslashes($_POST['ch']);
    $sel  = stripslashes($_POST['sel']);

  if(!empty($_POST['ch'])) { 
     foreach($_POST['ch'] as $check) { 
        $ch += $check; 
      }
  }


    $message = '
        <html>
                <head>
                    <title>Заявка</title>
                    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
                </head>
                <body>
                    <p>Значения чекбоксов    : '.$ch.'</p>
                    <p>Значение селекта    : '.$sel.'</p>
                </body>
        </html>';


    $mail = mail(CONTACT_FORM, $subject, $message,
        "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"
        ."From: ".$name." <".CONTACT_FORM.">\r\n"
        ."Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n"
        ."Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n");

    if($mail){
        echo "OK";
    }
?>
```

На почту приходит либо только одно значение чекбокса, либо `0`.

**Вопрос:** что я делаю не так в .php файле. Как можно исправить, что бы на почту приходили все значения чекбокса?

Comment: Вам нужно перебрать значения чекбокса через forech

Comment: Я в php вообще не разбираюсь, как это сделать не понятно!

Comment: Щас роспешу подождите

Comment: `if(!empty($_POST['ch'])) {
     foreach($_POST['ch'] as $check) {
             echo $check; 
     }
 }` Как потом в `$message` вставить все значения вот в чем проблема)?

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko, `name="ch"` -> `name="ch[]"` как-то так, кажется.

Comment: Это в html! Это уже узнала!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашла причину:

Не рабочий код:    `$ch += $check;`

Рабочий код:    `$ch .= $check;`

Получилось:

**.html:**

```
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="ch[]" id="ch-1" value="val-1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="ch[]" id="ch-2" value="val-2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="ch[]" id="ch-3" value="val-3">
</form>
```

**.php:**

```
<?php

    define("CONTACT_FORM", 'test@mail.ru'); 

    $subject = 'Заявка';

    $ch  = stripslashes($_POST['ch']);
    $sel  = stripslashes($_POST['sel']);

  if(!empty($_POST['ch'])) { 
     foreach($_POST['ch'] as $check) { 
        $ch .= $check; 
      }
  }


    $message = '
        <html>
                <head>
                    <title>Заявка</title>
                    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
                </head>
                <body>
                    <p>Значения чекбоксов    : '.$ch.'</p>
                    <p>Значение селекта    : '.$sel.'</p>
                </body>
        </html>';


    $mail = mail(CONTACT_FORM, $subject, $message,
        "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"
        ."From: ".$name." <".CONTACT_FORM.">\r\n"
        ."Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n"
        ."Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n");

    if($mail){
        echo "OK";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно получить все выбранные `checkbox`, и получить значение `select` и отправить в `contacts.php` AJAX запрос, передав в `data` значения `checkbox` и `select`

Вот пример:

```js
$(function(){
     var check = function(){
      var cBox = [];
            // в цикле собираем значения всех установленных чекбоксов и записываем их в массив cBox
      $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(){
       cBox.push($(this).attr("value"));
      });

            // получаем значение выбранного select
      var selectedValue = $("option:selected").attr("value");
          
            //debug
             alert("CheckBox [0]: " + cBox[0]);
             alert("CheckBox [1]: " + cBox[1]);
             alert("CheckBox [2]: " + cBox[2]);
             alert("Select: " + selectedValue);
            //debug
          
      $.ajax({
        url: 'contacts.php',
        type: 'post',
              // передаем в data массив со значениями checkbox и значение select
        data: { ch:cBox, sel:selectedValue }
      });
     }
     
     $("#submit").on("click", check);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="ch" id="ch-1" value="val-1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="ch" id="ch-2" value="val-2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="ch" id="ch-3" value="val-3">

  <select name="sel" >
    <option value="val-1" selected>val1</option>
    <option value="val-2">val2</option>
  </select>
  
  <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: А через php `for`? Этот вариант интересный, но мне не совсем подходит!

Comment: $checkBoxValues = "";
foreach ($c as $ch) {
    $checkBoxValues += $c + " ";
} а уже в HTML письма передавайте не $ch а $checkBoxValues

Comment: почему то 0 передается (

Answer (score 0):

Вот так точно все работает, скриншот

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**contacts.php**

```
<?php

if (isset($_REQUEST['ch'])) {
    print_r($_REQUEST['ch']);
}
```

**html**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="ch" id="ch-1" value="val-1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="ch" id="ch-2" value="val-2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="ch" id="ch-3" value="val-3">

  <select name="sel">
    <option value="val-1" selected>val1</option>
    <option value="val-2">val2</option>
  </select>

  <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<div id="result"></div>

<script>
  $(function() {
    var check = function() {
      var cBox = [];
      // в цикле собираем значения всех установленных чекбоксов и записываем их в массив cBox
      $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
        cBox.push($(this).attr("value"));
      });

      // получаем значение выбранного select
      var selectedValue = $("option:selected").attr("value");


      $.ajax({
        url: 'contacts.php',
        type: 'post',
        // передаем в data массив со значениями checkbox и значение select
        data: {
          ch: cBox,
          sel: selectedValue
        }
      }).done(function(msg) {
        $('#result').html(msg);
      });
    }

    $("#submit").on("click", check);
  });
</script>
```